# sending two binary message in one http rest request

Tags: rest, http, serialization, flask, protocol-buffers

I have REST service running on a server using Python flask. I have REST client which is built using java. I need to send two binary message in single Http REST request. The reason these are two because they both different protobuff message type but are inter-related to each other and should go in single HTTP request. How can we accomplish that at send and receive side.

Comment: You can use a multipart request. More information is available at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option here may be to simply declare a wrapper message type:

```
message FooRequest {
    // remove "required" if using proto3 syntax
    required Request1MessageType part1 = 1;
    required Request2MessageType part2 = 2;
}
```

and send a single `FooRequest` *composed of* the two inner messages. This is not always possible, however, in which case you'll have to implement your own framing mechanism inside the binary payload. A simple but pragmatic option might be to measure the size of the first message (in bytes) - i.e. `len`, and send:

```
[len, 4 bytes little endian][message 1, len bytes][message 2]
```

and decode it again at the other end - i.e. take the first 4 bytes and use that to calculate the ranges of the two inner messages. In anticipation of requiring more messages in the future, it *might* make sense to include a length prefix against *every* message (i.e. also include a length prefix for message 2) - but strictly speaking it would be redundant in the current case.